# Adding icons to ordered / unordered lists TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, dom, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I would like to add icons to the drop down menu of the ordered list (see the pic):

`advlist_bullet_styles: 'disc,circle,square'`:

[Image for the drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixuVw.jpg)

Is there a way to do that? I am sure there are tinyMCE pros on this site. I tried something like:

```
advlist_bullet_styles: [
 {icon: "bullist",
 type: 'disc'
 }
],
```

But it "kills" the editor. Obviously it's not the way to go. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We improved this menu in TinyMCE 5, using icon buttons:

[image: TinyMCE 5 List Icon Buttons]

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. To me TinyMCE 5 is a completely different beast. I've been using 4.5-4.7 for a while, really got used to it (modified some things here and there), so for me switching to 5 is going to be painful. :) I'd like to keep using 4.7 for now.

Comment: Any way you can help me? You know the script from start to finish is there a way to add similar buttons to 4.7?

Comment: I don't know if 4.x is flexible enough to do this, sorry. We built an completely new UI layer for 5.x which made it easy to do. While we will support 4.7 for a long time we are always interested in hearing what holds people back from upgrading. If you are happy to chat about this please log a support case (or even a github ticket).

Comment: I may submit a ticket at github. Just want to mention though, in N. America and probably some other countries people are still using Windows 7, XP and some older IE browsers. When I tested tinyMCE 5 I realized it didn't work in those OS. Some of my users are 50+ and use older OS as well. I do not know how many exactly, but if I switch to the 5.0 version they will feel left out. No doubt 5.0 is a cooler looking editor, but I wish you'd keep the support for older browsers and OS.

Comment: 4.9 doesn't work in those browsers either. I'm aware there are still users of those operating systems around, we still support 4.5 as LTS for them. Unfortunately a lot of the "cooler looking" things we do now are based on CSS3 and just aren't viable in old browsers.